# Insert a multiline string into another string

Tags: bash, sed, xml

I need to insert lines into an xml file :

Insert

```
  <one>
  </one>
```

into

```
<tags>
</tags>
```

To obtain

```
<tags>
  <one>
  </one>
</tags>
```

I tried this:

```
sed "s#\\(< /tags>\\)#${multiline_string}\1#"
```

but it loses the indentation.

Comment: Why is losing the indentation a problem? It should not be for XML files.

Comment: @Mat If it is data instead of just tags, it matters.

Comment: @Mat It is a problem because this xml (a maven pom) is read and modified by humans.

Comment: *@Philippe Blayo:* Your `sed` script wasn't far off the mark.  This works:  `sed "s|\(</tags>\)|${multiline_string//$'\n'/\n}\1|"` ... but larsks' *append* method may be more obvious.

Comment: @Peter.O Why did you submit that as a comment?

Comment: @Chris Down: It just felt like a comment :) ... but now that you mention it, I've noticed that it does offer someting different to the `sed ... a` method. It can use an arbitary string, without the need to manually include a trailing `\\` for all lines bar the last ... So, I've now added it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Mat said, indentation (and whitespace in general) is not important in XML files.  This:

```
<one><tags></tags></one>
```

Is exactly equivalent to:

```
<one>
 <tags>
 </tags>
</one>
```

But this will work while preserving indentation:

```
$ cat myfile.xml
<tags>
</tags>
$ sed '/<one>/ a\
  <tags>\
  </tags>
' myfile.xml > newfile.xml
$ cat newfile.xml
<one>
  <tags>
  </tags>
</one>
```

...but if you're working with XML, you might want to think about using a higher-level language that can actually parse XML and manipulate the tree programatically.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a mod to the code you show in the question.

Note that `$'\n'` is a *ksh* (also supported by *bash* and *zsh*) way to make a newline char, so adjust as needed if you are using another shell.

```
sed "s|\(</tags>\)|${multiline_string//$'\n'/\n}\1|g"
```

The trailing `g` is to cater for situations where you *may* have `</tags>` occurring more than once on a line..  It seems that it isn't needed for your `xml`, but it works either way.

Comment: Note that `\n` to mean a newline character in the RHS of the `s` command is not portable/standard. The standard way is a backslash followed by a newline character.