# Replace matches with multiline string using sed

Tags: sed, awk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Insert a multiline string into another string](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32584/insert-a-multiline-string-into-another-string)

I have a file called `foo.txt` containing:

```
foo
bar
baz
```

I want to replace every occurence of `bar` with a multiline string, stored in the variable `$bar`:

```
1
2
3
```

Resulting in:

```
foo
1
2
3
baz
```

I can do this in `awk` using:

```
echo "$bar" | awk '{
        if(FILENAME == "-")
        {
            if(i != "")
            {
                i = i"\n"
            }
            i = i$0
        }
        else
        {
            if($0 == "bar")
            {
                printf i
            }
            else
            {
                print
            }
        }
    }'
```

However trying to do the same in `sed` using `sed 's/bar/'"$bar"'/' foobar.txt` gives the error:

```
sed: 1: "s/bar/1
2
3/": unescaped newline inside substitute pattern
```

Can this be fixed?

If there is an even easier way of doing this using another standard tool, I would like to know that too.

Answer (score 5):

In `sed`, a newline character has to be escaped in the right hand side of the `s` command, so you need to write it:

```
sed 's/foo/1\
2\
3/g'
```

Some `sed` implementations also support the (non-standard):

```
sed 's/foo/1\n2\n3/g'
```

If `$bar` is to be the replacement, you'd need first to insert a backslash before every newline character. While you're at it, you should also insert a backslash before every slash, backslash and ampersand character.

Something like:

```
bar_escaped=$(printf '%s\n' "$bar" | sed 's,[\/&],\\&,g;s/$/\\/')
bar_escaped=${bar_escaped%?}
sed "s/foo/$bar_escaped/g"
```

Answer (score 1):

What I have done is create a `sed` pattern file and then call `sed` with that file specified instead of specifying the pattern within the command because you cannot do multi-lines on the command line (i.e. \n is not legal).  E.g.

```
sed -f pattern_file.sed infile.txt
```

In my case, I wanted to find every line that reads `alarm_if_fail: 1` and add `application: XYZ` on the very next line.  So **pattern_file.sed** looks as follows:

```
1,/^END/{


        s/^alarm_if_fail: 1$/&\
application: XYZ/


}
```

If **infile.txt** looks like

```
Unix
Stackexchange

alarm_if_fail: 1

ABC
```

Then `ed -f pattern_file.sed infile.txt` will return

```
Unix
Stackexchange

alarm_if_fail: 1
application: XYZ

ABC
```

Comment: The replacement parameter is not a constant string and will change, so I can't hard code it in the `pattern_file.sed`.

Comment: Is there any pattern to it?  Regex is pretty powerful these days

Comment: I'm talking about the new text inserted, the replacement string.