# Using sed in shell script with multiline variables

Tags: shell-script, sed, variable

I use shell scripts to setup different types of VMs. Often these scripts include multiline variables that need to be inserted into config files at certain positions using `sed`.

If I create them like this, everything is fine:

```
VAR="Config Line1\nConfig Line2\nConfig Line 3"
sed -i "/MatchingPattern/ a $VAR" somefile
```

This doesn't make the script very readable though, especially since the text blocks can be quite long.

If I write them like so:

```
VAR="Config Line1
Config Line2
Config Line 3"
sed -i "/MatchingPattern/ a $VAR" somefile
```

I get an error when running the script: `sed: -e expression #1, char 31: unknown command:`C'`

Is there a way to use `sed` with variables declared like that?

Comment: I find it easier to use awk, wrapped in a bash script, for this kinds of task. I use the Bash part to provide usage info (`-h` or `--help`), as well as create a temporary working directory that is automagically deleted when bash exits (i.e, an `EXIT` trap). That way, if there is an error or no required matches found, I can choose not to overwrite the original file.

Answer (score 3):

The standard syntax for the `a` command is:

```
sed -e 'a\
first line\
  second line\
last line'
```

[BSD (at least FreeBSD and OS/X) `sed` strips the leading blanks](/q/312579), and [needs the `-e` to work around a bug](/q/390845). GNU `sed` allows moving the first line to right after the `a\` as long as it's non-empty.

So, you'd need to preprocess the input:

```
VAR='content with
multiple lines
  some with lead blanks
or even backslash\'

preprocessed_VAR=$(printf '%s\n' "$VAR" |
  sed 's/\\/&&/g;s/^[[:blank:]]/\\&/;s/$/\\/')

sed -i -e "/MatchingPattern/a\\
${preprocessed_VAR%?}" somefile
```

(replace `-i` with `-i ''` on FreeBSD or OS/X).

On GNU/Linux and with the GNU shell (`bash`) or `zsh`, you can do instead:

```
sed -i '/MatchingPattern/r /dev/stdin' <<< "$VAR"
```

That works because `bash` and `zsh` implement here-strings with a deleted temporary files and /dev/stdin on Linux is implemented as a symlink to the file (which means it can be opened several time, and each time, it's open at the beginning).

Here you could also use GNU `awk` instead:

```
(export VAR
gawk -i /usr/share/awk/inplace.awk '{print}; /MatchingPattern/{print ENVIRON["VAR"]}' somefile)
```

**Do not use `-i inplace`** as `gawk` tries to load the `inplace` extension (as `inplace` or `inplace.awk`) from the current working directory first, where someone could have planted malware. The path of the `inplace` extension supplied with `gawk` may vary with the system, see the output of `gawk 'BEGIN{print ENVIRON["AWKPATH"]}'`

Or `perl` (where that `-i` comes from):

```
(export VAR
perl -pi -e '$_ .= "$ENV{VAR}\n" if /MatchingPattern/' somefile)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to the `sed` append command `a` needing a backslash after the actual `a`:

With GNU `sed`:

```
$ sed "/pattern/a\\$VAR" file.in >file.out
```

BSD `sed`, is, as far as I know, only able to insert a single line into a file with the `a` command, unless the newlines are properly escaped.

Closely related answer for how to solve this with BSD `sed`: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/60322

Comment: They can insert multiple line. That's what it's for. But you need a backslash at the end of all but the last line in all implementations. Otherwise, the second line would be treated as the next command in the sed script.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks, but that's what I believe I pointed out. "unless the newlines are properly escaped"

Comment: Yes, but that's the same in GNU sed or any sed.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas The difference is that GNU `sed` interprets the `\n` in the string.

Comment: Ah OK, though that's another (non-standard and non compliant as POSIX requires the `\n` to be inserted as `n`) way to "escape the newlines"